# How to comparison between variable1 and variable2

Tags: php

May I wanna ask about how to solve my problems 
I already have code :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($kataDasar); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($kataDasar1); $j++) {
        $jml = 0;
        if ($kataDasar[$i] == $kataDasar1[$j]) {
            $jml++;
        }
    }
    $tf[$i][$j] = $jml;
}
```

the problem is when I loop with variable `$kataDasar` it makes the value of   `$tf[$i][$j]` is wrong it should looping with other variable `$paragraf`, when I make the

```
for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++)
```

the comparison didnt work well.. can anyone help my problems..

Here My full Code

```
        echo '<p><b>Pemecahan Steamming</b></p>';
    print_r($kataDasar);
     echo "<br/><br/>";

    $kataDasar1 = Array();
foreach($kataDasar as $item){
        if($item != ''){
                if(!in_array($item, $kataDasar1) ){
                    $kataDasar1[] = $item;
                }
            }
        }

    print_r($kataDasar1);
     echo "<br/><br/>";

    //7. Perhitungan Bobot
    $tf = Array();
    $df = Array();      
    $q = Array();

    for($i=0; $i<count($kataDasar); $i++){


            for($j=0; $j<count($kataDasar1); $j++){
            $jml = 0;

                if ( $kataDasar[$i]== $kataDasar1[$j] ){
                    $jml++;

            }


            $tf[$i][$j] = $jml;

            if(isset($df[$j])){
                if($jml>0){
                    $df[$j] += 1;
                }
            }else{
                if($jml>0){
                    $df[$j] = 1;
                }else{
                    $df[$j] = 0;
                }

            }
            $q[$j] = 0;
        }

    //  }
    }


    $tmp_df = Array();
    $tmp_df = $df;
    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){ //Get 3 nilai df terbesar
        $max_df = max($tmp_df);
        $key_df = array_search($max_df, $tmp_df);
        $kata_q[] = $kataDasar1[$key_df];
        $q[$key_df] = 1;
        $tmp_df[$key_df] = 0;
    }
    echo '<p><b>Pembobotan DF dan Penentuan Query</b></p>';
     echo "df: " . "<br/>";
     print_r($df);
     echo "<br/>kata_q: " . "<br/>";
     print_r($kata_q);
     echo "<br/> q: " . "<br/>";
     print_r($q);
 echo "<br/><br/>";
 //exit();

    $idf = Array(); $i=0;
    foreach($df as $item){
        echo "Kata: ". $kataDasar1[$i] .", Par: " . count($paragraf) . ", df:" . $item . "<br/>";
        $idf[] = log10(count($paragraf) / $item);
        $i++;
    }

     echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo '<p><b>Hasil IDF</b></p>';
     print_r($idf);
     echo "<br/><br/>";
//  exit();

    $W = Array(); $W_q = Array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++){
        for($j=0; $j<count($kataDasar1); $j++){
            $W[$i][$j] = $tf[$i][$j] * $idf[$j];
            $W_q[$j] = $q[$j] * $idf[$j];
        }
    }
    echo '<p><b>Nilai Query</b></p>';
    print_r($W_q);
     echo "<br/><br/>";
        echo '<p><b>Nilai W</b></p>';
     print_r($W);


    $wdi = Array();
    $vektor = Array(); $vektor_q = Array();
    $tot_wdi = Array(); $tot_vektor = Array(); $tot_vektor_q = 0;

    for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++){
        $t_wdi = 0; $t_vektor = 0; $t_vektor_q = 0;
        for($j=0; $j<count($kataDasar1); $j++){
            $vektor[$i][$j] = $W[$i][$j] * $W[$i][$j];
            $vektor_q[$j] = $W_q[$j] * $W_q[$j];
            $wdi[$i][$j] = $vektor_q[$j] * $tf[$i][$j];

            $t_wdi += $wdi[$i][$j];
            $t_vektor += $vektor[$i][$j];
            $t_vektor_q += $vektor_q[$j];
        }
        $tot_wdi[] = $t_wdi;
        $tot_vektor[] = $t_vektor;
        $tot_vektor_q = $t_vektor_q;
    }

    print_r($vektor);

    print_r($tot_vektor);
```

Comment: Where does `$i` come from? I only see `$k`

Comment: Do you mean `$tf[$k][$j] = $jml;`?

Comment: sory I already edit it thanks for review my code

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?  What is `$paragraf`?  What values do these variables hold?  How is it "wrong"?  You have to actually explain the problem.

Comment: ok thanks I already add almost the full code, I wanna compare betwen $kataDasar[$i] and $kataDasar1[$j], and the problem is my looping code when I try use for ($i = 0; $i < count($kataDasar); $i++)  the value of comparison is right but the value of $tf[$i][$j] is wrong it should  for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++)

Comment: @AgungSetiabudi: *How* is the value "wrong"?  Try to understand that we don't know what your code is *supposed* to be doing.  If you can't describe the problem then nobody can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From your code. You are looping through $kataDasar with the increment variable as $k and accessing it with $i. You should compare with the right increment variable.  This should be the correct thing:

```
for($k=0; $k<count($kataDasar); $k++){
for($j=0; $j<count($kataDasar1); $j++){
$jml = 0;
if ( $kataDasar[$k]== $kataDasar1[$j] ){
$jml++;
}
// }
$tf[$i][$j] = $jml;
```